# What happens when min Heap or max Heap is full on insertion?

Tags: data-structures

Suppose we have minimum of `min_heap = [1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 13]`.

And the size of heap is finite as 6! It can't grow more than 10.

What happens when we put the greater element than any other elements in minimum heap? (ex. we put 15 into our heap in this case)

What will be the efficiency? O(K)? K= size of the heap!

Comment: "And the size of heap is finite as 6!" and "It can't grow more than 10." leave me puzzled. So, what is 6 and what is 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the "can't grow more than `K`" policy is implemented.

The most useful way to do that is to keep the best `K` elements at all times.
If so, inserting an element which is worse than the `K` best, naturally, does nothing.

The time for any insertion, successful or not, will be `O (log K)`, as usual.

Comment: Is it typical heap behavior? Or are we using modifying heap?

Comment: @JohnBaek If you have some particular heap implementation in mind (for example, the standard library of a certain programming language), please mention that in the question.

Comment: @JohnBaek If, on the other hand, you are going to implement the heap yourself, either you have a requirement what to do when the size is exceeded, or you can pick what to do for yourself, and do it. Generally, don't leave the readers guessing things like these, do provide details in your question to make it a good one.

Comment: My apology. I just had this coding interview question. The problem was to find K minimum values from the array. I asnwered it as we can use limited modified Heap so the efficiency was NLogK.